# Android autocomplete search with geocoding

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im doing a google maps app and im trying to add a search box with autocomplete with google maps places, i already have the code but it have 2 errors that i dont know how to solve it, i hope you can help me

**Error 1:**

```
@Override
public GeoSearchResult getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index);
}
```

the error is in the return line, it says "incompatible types, required:GeoSearchResult, found:java.lang.object"

**Error 2:**

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.geo_search_result_item, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.geo_search_result_text)).setText(getItem(position).getAddress());

        return convertView;
    }
```

The error is in the "convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.geo_search_result_item, parent, false);" line, it says "cannot resolve geo_search_result_item" and thats the way a get the code

The full code Below

**GeoAutoCompleteAdapter.class**

```
package com.example.luiggi.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by andre_000 on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class GeoAutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 10;
    private Context mContext;
    private List resultList = new ArrayList();

    public GeoAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public GeoSearchResult getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.geo_search_result_item, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.geo_search_result_text)).setText(getItem(position).getAddress());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    List locations = findLocations(mContext, constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = locations;
                    filterResults.count = locations.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    resultList = (List) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {

                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    private List<GeoSearchResult> findLocations(Context context, String query_text) {

        List<GeoSearchResult> geo_search_results = new ArrayList<GeoSearchResult>();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 15 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(query_text, 15);

            for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){
                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);
                if(address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() != -1)
                {
                    geo_search_results.add(new GeoSearchResult(address));
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return geo_search_results;
    }
}
```

**GeoSearchResult.class**

```
import android.location.Address;

/**
 * Created by andre_000 on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class GeoSearchResult {

    private Address address;

    public GeoSearchResult(Address address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress(){

        String display_address = "";

        display_address += address.getAddressLine(0) + "\n";

        for(int i = 1; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        {
            display_address += address.getAddressLine(i) + ", ";
        }

        display_address = display_address.substring(0, display_address.length() - 2);

        return display_address;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String display_address = "";

        if(address.getFeatureName() != null)
        {
            display_address += address + ", ";
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        {
            display_address += address.getAddressLine(i);
        }

        return display_address;
    }
}
```

**GeoSearchResult.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/geo_search_result_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it was gone after a new rebuild.`Build > Rebuild Project` But then the getAddress() on the same line couldn't be resolved but it was fixed but removing and adding it again.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the support library instead of ActionBarSherlock, which is deprecated for a long time now.

Comment: using suppot library how can do a searchview for google maps places??